# Why does one of these icons work but the other does not?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a bubble with an exit button that works. The one on the right works correctly. The one on the left does not work correctly for some reason.

[image: Bubble on right is the exit button that works]

Code that creates the bubbles

```
var bubble = "<div class = 'bubble' id='bubble"+driver_id+"' style=top:" + counter * 100 + "px';>"+driver_name+"<br>"+time+"<a id='"+driver_id+"' class='homeDriver'><span class='icon home'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+"' class='notifyDriver'><span class='icon comments'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+"' class='pauseDriver'><span class ='icon pause'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+"' class='show'><span class='icon list'></a></span><div class ='btn-exit'><span class ='icon close'></span></div></div>";

var smsBubble ="<div class = 'smsBubble"+driver_id+"' id ='smsBubble'><span class ='icon notifyComments'></span>"+driver_name+"<input type = 'text' class ='textNotify' id='message'/><div class='buttons'><a id = '"+driver_id+"'><button class='btn-sendSms'>Send</a></button><a id = '"+driver_id+"' class ='sendSms'><button class='btn-sendSmsClose'>Send & Close Card</a></button></div><div class = 'btn-exit'><span class ='icon close'></span></div></div>";

$("#bubble"+driver_id).on('click', '.btn-exit', function(){
    $("#bubble"+driver_id).remove();
 })
$("#smsBubble").on('click', '.btn-exit', function(){
    console.log("Testing");
    $(".smsBubble"+driver_id).remove();
```

CSS for bubbles

```
.icon::before
    {
        display: inline-block;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
.close::before
    {
        font-size:20px;
        position: relative;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 110px;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f410";
    }
    .smsClose::before
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 190px;
        right: 10px;
        float: right;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f410";
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: because you are adding multiple elements with the same id.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings of HTML are really hard to read and understand.

Consider using string templates, instead.

Your existing code (with carriage returns added):

```js
var bubble = "<div class = 'bubble' id='bubble"+driver_id+"' style=top:" +
  counter * 100 + "px';>"+driver_name+"<br>"+time+"<a id='"+driver_id+
  "' class='homeDriver'><span class='icon home'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+
  "' class='notifyDriver'><span class='icon comments'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+
  "' class='pauseDriver'><span class ='icon pause'></a></span><a id='"+driver_id+
  "' class='show'><span class='icon list'></a></span><div class ='btn-exit'><span class ='icon close'></span></div></div>";
```

That same code converted to use string templates:

```js
var bubble = `
  <div class = "bubble" id="bubble${driver_id}"
    style="top:${counter * 100}px">
    ${driver_name}<br>
    ${time}
    <a id="${driver_id}" class="homeDriver">
      <span class="icon home">
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="${driver_id}" class="notifyDriver">
      <span class="icon comments">
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="${driver_id}" class="pauseDriver">
      <span class ="icon pause">
      </a>
    </span>
    <a id="${driver_id}" class="show">
      <span class="icon list">
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class ="btn-exit">
      <span class ="icon close"></span>
    </div>
  </div>`;
```

It should be clear that the second version is easier to read and find errors.

Notice that you have this pattern in multiple places:

```html
<a>
  <span>
  </a>
</span>
```

That's invalid, you need to close the `span` before closing the `a`:

```html
<a>
  <span></span>
</a>
```

You also have several `a` tags with the same id:

```js
<a id='"+driver_id+"' class='homeDriver'>
```

That is also invalid. An id attribute may be used only once.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two mistakes in the smsbubble code, try:

```
$("#smsBubble").on('click', '.btn-exit', function(){
    console.log("Testing");
    $("#smsBubble").remove();
})
```